# Use tomcat7x when binding Cargo start/stop goals to Maven integration-test phases

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, pom.xml, cargo

I have successfully configured Cargo in my pom.xml to start tomcat7x when executing the 'mvn cargo:run' command. This is the Cargo plugin configuration I used:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
        <containerUrl>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.30/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.30.zip</containerUrl>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And that's fine and works well. However, I now want to bind the Cargo start and stop goals to the maven pre-integration-test and post-integration-test phases. I use the same configuration as above but also add executions to the plugin as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
        <containerUrl>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.30/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.30.zip</containerUrl>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-container</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
             <id>stop-container</id>
             <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>stop</goal>
             </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This does also work very nicely, starts the container in the pre-integration-test, executes my integration tests, and then stops the container in the post-integration-test phase. The only problem is that it is not the tomcat7x container I configured, it starts the default Jetty container and seems to ignore my tomcat7x configuration.

How can I get these executions to work with the tomcat7x container that I have configured?

Thanks.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and found that [this answer][1] solved it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079813/cargo-maven-plugin-start-goal-ignores-configuration-run-works-fine